# How do people 'lookup' values from calculated surfaces?

Tags: interpolation

I have been wondering how the following situation is / should be implemented.

Consider some kind of surface $z = f(x,y)$ which has to be pre-calculated; the shape of this surface would not have a closed-form solution, but would instead be calibrated by some time-consuming numerical methods, which are updated asynchronously (e.g. some overnight calibration job).

Given this surface (which presumably is defined over some discrete meshgrid), how do we perform a 'look-up', such that we can recover $z$ for any $x$ and $y$?

I can't tell if this is a complex interpolation or optimisation problem, or if there are really trivial ways that this is achieved in practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear interpolation in 2d is not much more complicated that in 1d:
\begin{align}
\color{red}{f(x,y_i)}&=\frac{f(x_i,y_i)(x_{i+1}-x)+f(x_{i+1},y_i)(x-x_i)}{x_{i+1}-x_i}\,,\\[3mm]
\color{red}{f(x,y_{i+1})}&=\frac{f(x_i,y_{i+1})(x_{i+1}-x)+f(x_{i+1},y_{i+1})(x-x_i)}{x_{i+1}-x_i}\,,\\[3mm]
f(x,y)&=\frac{\color{red}{f(x,y_i)}(y_{i+1}-y)+\color{red}{f(x,y_{i+1})}(y-y_i)}{y_{i+1}-y_i}\,.
\end{align}

Comment: Of course, as in 1D, the interpolation needs to be checked for arbitrage possibilities. But that does not mean that a bilinear interpolation is not feasible.

Comment: Thanks; so your suggestion is that we interpolate linearly between known points in the meshgrid. Presumably we can interpolate using splines to better match the convexity (is this the arbitrage-check that Kermittfrog is referring to?)